# Cuál es el error en mi código y mi circuito?

Tags: arduino

```
//chequeo de entradas, salidas y presentes
este es el código:
int pir_pin = 2;
int pir_pon = 3;
int led1 = 4;
int led2 = 5;
int dato;
int entradas = 0;
int salidas = 0;
int presentes;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(pir_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pir_pon, INPUT);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Escribe 1 para ver entradas, 0 para ver salidas y 'p' para ver los presentes en el momento");
}

void loop() {
  // chequeo de entradas y salidas con sensores:
  if (digitalRead(pir_pin) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    entradas++;
  } else if (digitalRead(pir_pon) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    salidas++;
  }
  presentes = entradas - salidas;

  // chequeo de entradas y salidas por el monitor
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    dato = Serial.read();
    if (dato == '1') {
      Serial.print("Las entradas han sido: ");
      Serial.println(entradas);
    } else if (dato == '0') {
      Serial.print("Las salidas han sido: ");
      Serial.println(salidas);
    } else if (dato == 'p') {
      Serial.print("Los presentes son: ");
      Serial.println(presentes);
    }
  }
}
```

este es el circuito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi programa es un contador de personas cuando entran y salen de un lugar, estoy utilizando 2 sensores pir, cables macho-hembra y cables macho-macho para hacer el circuito.
Intente cambiar varias veces la configuración, pero nada pasó. Además mi sensor es muy sensible y detecta todo. quiero que sea menos sensible

No puedo proveerles una línea de error porque no la hay, solo es que creo que el código con compagina con el circuito.
quisiera que me dijeran cual es el problema de compatibilidad entre mi código y mi circuito

Comment: Olvidaste señalar cual es el problema en todo el asunto